# Amazon web services and ubuntu 10.04 ec2 instance

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created ubuntu 10.04 ec2 image and now I need to install tomcat apache and jdk6 on my instance but whenever I use the command `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk` or `sudo apt-get install tomcat6 admin` or `sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools`

```
Package ec2-api-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ec2-api-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package ec2-api-tools has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option is to add their [official repository](https://launchpad.net/~awstools-dev/+archive/awstools) to apt - this will provide you up to date AWS tools:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:awstools-dev/awstools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools -y
```

This is extremely useful for farther releases and and for up to date official bug fixes etc. just by running the usual

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu doesn't have the Sun JDKs available by default so in /etc/apt/sources.list uncomment:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

ec2-api-tools requires the multiverse lines in sources.list to be uncommented first (remember to apt-get update also).

Comment: Make sure you're not pointing to 'hardy' for the multiverse lines.  I was still getting the error message "Package ec2-api-tools has no installation candidate" until I replaced 'hardy' with 'lucid'.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused, if you just want to install Java and Tomcat, why are you also trying to install the ec2 tools?

In any case, I also want to mention the free [BitNami Cloud Tools installer](http://bitnami.org/tools/cloud) (disclaimer: I am one of the developers). It includes the JDK and all EC2-related tools. We keep it fairly up-to-date and can run as a regular user.