# Not able to install aws ec2 api tools in ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Amazon web services and ubuntu 10.04 ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337138/amazon-web-services-and-ubuntu-10-04-ec2-instance)

I am selected an ubuntu ec2 instance and I am trying to install ec2-tools, but using sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools i am encountering an error which says no package found. How do I install ec2-api-tools

Comment: I explained this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337138/amazon-web-services-and-ubuntu-10-04-ec2-instance/5344776#5344776. Why have you opened a new post instead of answering in the old one. This is just spamming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `awstools` repository and update apt.

1. `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:awstools-dev/awstools`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools`

Another option is to download *ec2-api-tools* from amazon website and configure them for your system. For path configuration see [this link](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-getting-started-with-amazon-ec2).

Regards,
Sanket Dangi

Comment: Think this should be `ec2-api-tools`?

Comment: This what has worked for me $ sudo sed -i.dist 's,universe$,universe multiverse,' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools ec2-ami-tools